# Iterating over columns to create many graphs

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, histogram

I want to check the normality assumption of many different response variables, so I wrote function to create a histogram of each variable, faceted by each predictor. It works great, but I want to also overlay the normal curve over it, which is where I am getting stuck. I know my code isn't working and I know that writing "data$i" isn't the solution, but I'm not sure what is.

Thanks for any help!

```
colNames <- names(content)
for(i in colNames){
  plt <- ggplot(data = data , aes_string(x=i))+
    geom_histogram()+
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, colour = "red",
                  arg = list(mean = mean(data$i, na.rm = TRUE),
                             sd = sd(data$i, na.rm = TRUE)))+
    facet_wrap(level ~ .)
  print(plt)
  }
```

Comment: The `$` subsetting method doesn't work with variables, it needs a symbol. The easiest way is to use double bracket subsetting `data[[i]]`, which works because `data.frame`s are essentially lists.

Comment: I tried this as well but the resulting normal curves are still obviously incorrect.